# zsh: Make foo<Esc>* expand foo* immediately

Tags: command-line, zsh, wildcards, autocomplete

I recently switched from bash to zsh. One difference is that when typing a command in bash and I do Esc-* (in vi editing mode), bash will expand the glob inline immediately. For example, if I type:

```
$ ls
bar foo1 foo2 foo3
$ cp foo<Esc>*
```

bash will change the command to:

```
$ cp foo1 foo2 foo3
```

and position the cursor at the end of the line and put me back in insert mode. How can I get zsh to do the same thing?

Comment: See `info zsh _all_matches`

Answer (score 1):

In the default configuration, you get this effect from [`expand-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-expand_002dword) which is bound to `^X *` (<kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>) in Emacs mode (if you want it in Vi mode, you'll have to bind it to a key). Unlike `ESC *` in bash, `^X *` in zsh also expands variable and command substitutions.

Additionally, in the default configuration, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> after a word containing wildcards expands it to the list of matches.

If you have the option [`glob_complete`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-GLOB_005fCOMPLETE) on, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through the matches rather than inserting all of them. In this case, you can assign a key to the [`_all_matches` completer](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fall_005fmatches) (mentioned by [Stéphane Chazelas in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591624/zsh-make-fooesc-expand-foo-immediately#comment1103360_591624)). Quoting the example code in the manual:

```
setopt glob_complete
zle -C all-matches complete-word _generic
bindkey '^Xa' all-matches
zstyle ':completion:all-matches::::' completer _all_matches _complete
zstyle ':completion:all-matches:*' insert true
```

The difference between the completion widgets (default <kbd>Tab</kbd> and this `all-matches`) and the built-in widget `expand-word` is that `expand-word` does shell filename expansion, no matter what the completion context is, whereas <kbd>Tab</kbd> and `all-matches` use the completion context to determine how to process wildcards. For example, after `rmdir *`, `^X*` expands to all files whereas `^Xa` expands to directories only.

Comment: Since I want <Esc>* not ^X*, I did `bindkey '\e*' all-matches`. Everything else is the same. However, it doesn't work. Zsh just beeps. I've also found this link similar to (but not exactly the same as) yours. It doesn't work either. https://blog.iany.me/2013/04/select-multiple-zsh-completions-item/

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Indeed it works with my configuration, but not in the default configuration. Apparently what makes it work in my configuration is `setopt glob_complete`, without which a simple `Tab` does what you want. I'd forgotten that the `glob_complete` effect was not the default.

Comment: Adding `setopt glob_complete` changes nothing. Tab also does nothing. FYI, my current set of zsh options starts here: https://github.com/paul-j-lucas/env/blob/master/dotfiles/bashrc#L18

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Oh, you aren't using the “new-style completion” (`compinit`). Still, even without it, `Tab` inserts all matches for wildcards by default. Your configuration file is too long and complex for me to debug, but if `echo *<TAB>` doesn't replace the `*` by the list of files in the current directory, it must be due to something in there.